# Why does Euler's number occur in the Chudnovsky Formula for calculating $\pi$?

Tags: pi, modular-forms, euler-mascheroni-constant

The Chudnovsky Formula for calculating $\pi$ reads:

$$\frac{1}{\pi} = 12 \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^k (6k)! (545140134k + 13591409)}{(3k)!(k!)^3 640320^{3k + 3/2}}$$

If you double the second coefficient, you obtain

$$2\cdot13591409=27182818$$

which is the first 8 digits of Euler's number.

Any ideas on why this happens? Or is it just coincidence?

Comment: While this is a very famous formula, I doubt if anyone before you noticed this fact. My guess is that it is a coincidence but who knows.

Comment: If it is actually a coincindence, it is a really surprising one. I wonder how the large coefficients emerged and how this formula was found. Maybe, this would shed light on the question.

Comment: @Peter: The most detailed description of how the coefficients emerged is in chapter 10 of my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00533, but I don't see a deeper reason why the decimals of $e$ should appear here...